# Any specific "way" a python application needs to be written to make it "deployable"?

Tags: python, deployment, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have written a Python application that communicates with Google Cloud Datastore and Storage. This application has no front-end, but back-end and also re-runs periodically.

Pointers:
1. Without using Flask, I can run application periodically by keeping it in an infinite loop and making it sleep for a time period.
2. With using Flask (and removing infinite loop), whenever I refresh localhost server, the program runs properly. Just for the sake of showing something on localhost page, I returned "some string"

Problem:
Having application properly deployed on local server using Flask, I am facing challenges deploying on Google Cloud Platform (GCP). I tried using app.yaml file that I used in hello world program and used `gcloud preview app deploy`. It gets stuck while `Updating Service[default]...failed`

It would be great if someone has idea about ways to deploy an application on GCP. 
Thank you.

Comment: do you have a version of python installed on the server that supports the libraries you are using in your app?

Comment: @glls Would you please elaborate ? I am not sure if I have done that... Do we need to inform server about this ?

Comment: my bad, "I have written a Python application that communicates with Google Cloud Datastore and Storage"  for some reason I thought you were trying to run the code on the server. Unless this is the case? "Having application properly deployed on local server using Flask, I am facing challenges deploying on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)"

Comment: @glls Yes, I am trying to deploy the code on server... In the app.yaml file, I have already mentioned runtime (python) and version (2.7).

Comment: Ok, so. in your app (or pytohn script) you will need to declare the libraries you want to install to run your app. I can demonstrate if you have no idea how. I Do this on AWS instances when running python scripts, since I sometimes add other libraries that might not be on the server to my scripts

Comment: @glls I had already created a file "requirements.txt" where I mentioned all the supporting libraries. It turned out I ignored fundamental ones, and that's why I couldn't deploy. Thank you so much...

Comment: no prob. glad you were able to find the issue